# JOIN Between OPOR (Purchase orders) and ORDR (Sales orders) (SAP Business One - SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hana

I am currently working in SAP Business One and came across the following problem:

I can't connect the purchase to sales orders.
I used the OITM Table to make a connection between the two.

I Tried the following:

```
SELECT T0."DocNum", T0."CardName", T0."NumAtCard", T0."DocDate", T0."ReqDate", T0."U_ACM_ORDERINFO", T4."DocNum", T4."CardName", T4."U_ACM_CONTAINERLOAD", T4."U_ACM_O_ETD", T4."U_ACM_A_ETD" 
FROM ORDR T0 
INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry" 
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1."ItemCode" = T2."ItemCode" 
INNER JOIN POR1 T3 ON T2."ItemCode" = T3."ItemCode" 
INNER JOIN OPOR T4 ON T3."DocEntry" = T4."DocEntry"
```

Unfortunatly, when executing this statement, the outcome is not unique.
[image]

Can someone help me in making a good connection between the purchase and sales orders and also make the lines unique

The outcome would be something like this

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show sample input data and desired results. It's not clear what "not unique" means or why those output `DocNum`s (should) correspond to each other. How do you conceptually define that a SO is related to a PO?

Comment: Without knowledge of your schema and what these poorly named tables actually represent, it is difficult to help. Your use of cryptic alias names does not help.

Comment: @SMor I changed the table names to the tables that I used in the select statement. Hope it helps

Comment: @underscore_d I made sample data of the current and desired situation, hope it helps

Comment: @RedwanAgharoud Can you show us the layout of the five tables you want to join? Also, as **underscore_d** said, how do you know that a SO is related to a PO? Does your organization purchase goods that it then resells?  Or are the POs placed by customers, and then turned into SO's?

Comment: @AnnL.You are right, products are purchased and resold. I don't know how I can show the layout of the tables.

Comment: @AnnL. You can find a detailed information about the tables in this webpage ([SAPTables](http://www.saptables.net/)) . The SAP B1 version is not important, maybe the version that he are using is 9.X.

Comment: Has Serial Number registered in SAP the products you want to monitor? In this case, maybe you can monitor each product individually.

Answer (score 3):

**There are not a relationship between the purchases and the sales order**.

Normally, the purchase code is not the same as the sales code, I do not know if you have count with it.

You can use two diferents queries and join it for know the amount of the sales and the amout of the purchase quantity in a concrete time. However, I do not think that you want this.

Comment: Late to the party, but this is not true. See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue, so i thought i'd share my findings for others to come.

The connection/link between sales orders and purchase orders is done from RDR1.PoTrgEntry = OPOR.DocEntry.

Full example:

```
SELECT T0.DocNum 'Sales order',
 T1.LineNum, T1.ItemCode, T1.Quantity, T1.ShipDate,
 T2.DocNum 'Purchase order', T2.CardCode, T2.CardName
 FROM ORDR T0  
 INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.DocEntry = T1.DocEntry 
 INNER JOIN OPOR T2 On T2.DocEntry = T1.PoTrgEntry
```